# Azure Serverless Insert data into Cosmos dB using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-cosmosdb, serverless

All, I am trying to find some documentation to insert data into the Cosmos DB collection using my serverless function. I am using httptriggers to get the data from request and insert it into cosmos.

I am not able to find any documentation on this.. especially using javascript.

This is what I have as of now but itis throwing errors.
**My Index.js file**

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    const endpoint = "https://localhost:8081/";
    const key = "key here";
    const database = "NodeSamples";
    const container = "Data";
    const itemDefs = JSON.parse({"fname":"John","lname":"Doe"});
    await Promise.all(itemDefs.map((itemDef: any) => container.items.create(itemDef)));
};
```

Any help would be gladly appreciated

Comment: Could you tell me what is " your serverless function"? Is that you use Azure Function?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the documentation from [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-integrate-store-unstructured-data-cosmosdb?tabs=javascript#update-the-function-code) and you need to import the necessary package

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {

    // We need both name and task parameters.
    if (req.query.name && req.query.task) {

        // Set the output binding data from the query object.
        context.bindings.taskDocument = req.query;

        // Success.
        context.res = {
            status: 200
        };
    }
    else {
        context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: "The query options 'name' and 'task' are required."
        };
    }
};
```

Comment: can you share the link?  itis missing.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-integrate-store-unstructured-data-cosmosdb?tabs=javascript#update-the-function-code

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is use the Cosmos DB SDK in Azure Functions, you can:

#### Use the Cosmos DB JS SDK

Package: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-js/

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections#cosmosclient-code-example-javascript

```
const cosmos = require('@azure/cosmos');
const endpoint = process.env.COSMOS_API_URL;
const key = process.env.COSMOS_API_KEY;
const { CosmosClient } = cosmos;

const client = new CosmosClient({ endpoint, key });
const container = client.database("MyDatabaseName").container("MyContainerName");

module.exports = async function (context) {
    const itemDefs = JSON.parse('[{"id":"SomeId", "fname":"John","lname":"Doe"}]');
    await Promise.all(itemDefs.map((itemDef: any) => container.items.create(itemDef)));
}
```

#### Use the Cosmos DB Function Bindings

The bindings are an easy way to interact with Cosmos DB, as they cover basic scenarios without having to do things like maintaining a singleton client instance, but if you want to do many things (query documents, save them, update, etc) on the same Function execution, then your best bet is to go with the first option.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2#output---javascript-examples

```
module.exports = function (context) {
  const itemDefs = JSON.parse('[{"id":"SomeId", "fname":"John","lname":"Doe"}]');
  context.bindings.documentsToSave = itemDefs;
  context.done();
};
```

Having defined your `function.json` with the binding:

```
{
    "name": "documentsToSave",
    "type": "cosmosDB",
    "databaseName": "MyDatabase",
    "collectionName": "MyCollection",
    "createIfNotExists": true,
    "connectionStringSetting": "MyAccount_COSMOSDB",
    "direction": "out"
}
```